# Perform the indicated operations and simplify

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$${2x^2+5x-3\over16x^2+26x+9}\cdot{10x^2+13x+4\over5x^2+11x-12}\cdot{35x^2-38x+8\over x^2+x-2}$$
Please help me. I'm having a hard time with 3 terms.

Comment: I did some editing for formatting. Please check to see I didn't introduce any mistakes in the statement.

Comment: Try showing what these quadratic expressions look like when factored

Comment: I inserted asterisks to present a multiplication symbol. @GerryMyerson

Comment: @Henry, my guess is that factoring is exactly the difficulty OP is having.

Comment: @Gerry: Perhaps, but being able to do this, such as $10x^2+13x+4= \left( 2\,x+1\right) \,\left( 5\,x+4\right)$, is the first step and ikaidubidu could at least attempt this six times (rather than three)

Comment: @Henry, I interpreted "I'm having a hard time with 3 terms" to mean "I'm having a hard time dealing with expressions like $2x^2+5x-3$ that have 3 terms in them". I think you're interpreting it to mean, "I was able to factor 3 of the quadratics, but not the other three". OP has not done anything in this discussion to establish a lower bound on algebraic capabilities.

Comment: @Gerry: I was reading "I'm having a hard time with 3 terms" as $a \times b \times c$ where $a={2x^2+5x-3\over16x^2+26x+9}$ etc.  I was not clear factoring had even occurred as an idea to ikaidubidu

Comment: @Henry, I like that interpretation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT: Factor!

$${2x^2+5x-3\over16x^2+26x+9}\cdot{10x^2+13x+4\over5x^2+11x-12}\cdot{35x^2-38x+8\over x^2+x-2} $$ $$= \dfrac{(2x -1)\color{red}{\bf (x+3)}}{(8x+9)\color{blue}{\bf (2x + 1)}}\cdot \dfrac{(5x + 4)\color{blue}{\bf (2x + 1)}}{\color{green}{\bf (5x-4)}\color{red}{\bf (x+3)}} \cdot \dfrac{(7x - 2)\color{green}{\bf (5x - 4)}}{(x+2)(x-1)}$$

Cancel common factors in numerator and denominator.

Comment: after i cancel, what should i do? i dont get it.

Comment: You'll be left with three factors in the numerator, and three in the denominator. $$\frac{(2x-1)(5x+4)(7x-2)}{(8x +9)(x+2)(x -1)}$$ That is as simplified as it gets, unless you want to expand the factors, but there's really no reason to do so.

Comment: can i ask another question, in dividing terms with exponents, you will subtract the exponents, right? then if it is negative, what should i do? @amWhy

Comment: If you want to ask another question, it's best to post another question, not to put it into the comments of this question.

Comment: @amWhy nice hint $\huge\color{blue}{+}^+$

Comment: @amWhy: I love the color coding, I need to use that more! +1

Answer (score 0):

**Factor, and then cancel, BEFORE multiplying.**

I see students faced with $\dfrac{20\cdot19\cdot18\cdot17\cdot16\cdot15}{6\cdot5\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1}$ grabbing their calculators and evaluating the large number in the numerator.  But the $20$ cancels $5\cdot4$ and the $18$ cancels $6\cdot3$ and $\dfrac{16}{2}=8$, so you've got $19\cdot17\cdot2\cdot15$.

The same thing applies to polynomials.  I've seen students faced with expressions like the one in this problem multiplying out the polynomials in the numerator, and similarly in the denominator.  You're guaranteed to get lost that way.